# Adding userlocation annotation by tap

Tags: ios, swift

How can I add an annotation to mapView when a button is tapped? The annotation is placed from the user location.

My code below will run successfully, but when you tap the button `addAnnotation`, the app will crash. It says:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
var myLocation : CLLocation!

    @IBAction func addAnnotation(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

            let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: myLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: myLocation.coordinate.longitude)
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

            self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
            self.myLocation = locations.last as CLLocation!
        }

        let addPin = MKPointAnnotation()
        addPin.coordinate = center
        addPin.title = "ENDELIG!"
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(addPin)
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide details about the crash. What's the complete error message? Where does it crash?

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Update your question with that info along with the exact line of code causing the issue.

Comment: Now it should be fine

Comment: For the 3rd time now, point out the exact line of code causing the error.